# python http server: Get response headers as the would be sent

Tags: python, http, httpserver

When using the code as below, the httpServer automatically adds some headers to the outgoing HTTP response (such as the 'Host' header). How can I get access to all the headers that are auto-generated and sent to the client?

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("Hello World", "utf-8"))
        __want to read all response.headers here as the would be sent to the client... self.response.headers doesn't contain them, they are not added till this method returns?...___

webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
webServer.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Host` header is a request header. You can't see it in an HTTP response.

In Python 3.8, `self._headers_buffer` is a `list` which contains the HTTP response status line as well as response headers only after you've called `self.send_response` and before you call either `self.end_headers` or `self.flush_headers`.

The buffer is reset to an empty `list` after either of those calls.